# JComboBox in a JScrollPane not scrolling

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jcombobox, miglayout

I have added mutiple `JcomboBox` inside a panel and embedeed the panel into a `JScrollPane`.The Scrollpane is set as ContentPane for `JDialog`. The problem is when I try to scroll the scroll pane it doesn't do anything when hovering the mouse over a combo box component. Is there any way I can stop this behavior so that it is possible to scroll the panel when hovering the mouse over a combo box?

Scrolling works fine on other areas of the pane.

Here is the code;

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

public class Window extends JDialog {

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Window dialog = new Window();
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     */
    public Window() {
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 153);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        {
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
            getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            {
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                scrollPane.setViewportView(panel);
                panel.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow]", "[][][][][][][]"));
                {
                    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
                    panel.add(comboBox, "cell 0 0,growx");
                }
                {
                    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
                    panel.add(comboBox, "cell 0 1,growx");
                }
                {
                    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
                    panel.add(comboBox, "cell 0 2,growx");
                }
                {
                    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
                    panel.add(comboBox, "cell 0 3,growx");
                }
                {
                    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
                    panel.add(comboBox, "cell 0 4,growx");
                }
                {
                    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
                    panel.add(comboBox, "cell 0 5,growx");
                }
                {
                    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
                    panel.add(comboBox, "cell 0 6,growx");
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: *"so that it is possible to scroll the panel when hovering the mouse over a combo box?"* I'm not sure I understand (or would agree), you mean that the MouseWheel is not scrolling the components when the mouse is over the combobox?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, It's not scrolling anything. I would like the `JScrollPane` to scroll when using the mouse wheel and hovering over a `JComboBox`.

Comment: Downloaded MigLayout 4.0, ran your program on my portable (Win 8.1, java 1.7.0), hovered over combobox, used mousewheel to scroll -> scroll pane scrolls down.

Comment: @TT. I changed out `MigLayout` for `GridBagLayout`. My JRE is 1.8.0_71. Tried it on both Windows 7 & Windows 10. No difference.

Comment: Any solution till now @psycotik?

Comment: @selcuk bozdag. None

Comment: I found a bug filed in JDK here http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8033069. Could it be about what you're asking?